# ftplib vs urllib2?

Tags: python, ftp, urllib2, ftplib

I can't figure out how to pick between `ftplib` and `urllib2` for downloading a file over FTP. As far as I can tell, they work comparably well, and most recommendations just seem to presume one or the other without listing pros/cons. Furthermore, there are other libraries to try, too.

How should I pick in general? It's not just a matter of finding something that works, I've done that already two different ways. I'm wondering what the Right choice is. My basic thought is to use `ftplib` since it is after all an ftp server...

In my specific case, I'm dealing with very large files (several gb) on public servers. I'd like to get a progress bar of some sort. Since the files are so large, it would be nice to have a resume capability... but those are optional -- just to be nice to people who will use my code. I don't want to use a library that is already marked for deprecation.

Comment: I'd also consider [`pyftplib`](http://code.google.com/p/pyftpdlib/) which is used by projects such as bazaar and Chromium.

Comment: Ok this is not directly relevant, but do you consider an out-of-python solution such as the famous rsync? Because for that size of file, the transmit would better happen in the background, i.e. asynchornized, anyway.

Comment: my first solution was to do curl through subprocess, but that was failing for some reason, so I figured a more pythonic way would give better error reporting, timeouts, etc. It's necessary for my script to wait until the download completes, because afterwards I run tests using the file.